# openldap ACLs not read

Tags: linux, unix, ldap, debian, openldap

I'm running ldap 2.4.40 on debian and I'm having problems with configuring new acls in openldap. Here are the acls that I have configured:

```
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=extern
 al,cn=auth manage by * break
olcAccess: {1}to attrs=userPassword by self write by anonymous auth by dn="c
 n=admin,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx" write by * none
olcAccess: {2}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {3}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=xxxxx,dc=cc" write by * read
olcAccess: {4}to attrs=userPassword by dn="cn=extra,ou=system,dc=xxxxx
 ,dc=xx" write
olcAccess: {5}to * by dn="cn=extra,ou=system,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx" write
```

and here is the debug trace when I do a slapadd:

```
57271dfe => acl_get: [4] attr children
57271dfe => acl_mask: access to entry "dc=test,dc=com,ou=accounts,dc=xxxxxx,dc=xx", attr "children" requested
57271dfe => acl_mask: to all values by "cn=extra,ou=system,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx", (=0)
57271dfe <= check a_dn_pat: self
57271dfe <= check a_dn_pat: cn=admin,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx
57271dfe <= check a_dn_pat: *
57271dfe <= acl_mask: [3] applying read(=rscxd) (stop)
57271dfe <= acl_mask: [3] mask: read(=rscxd)
57271dfe => slap_access_allowed: add access denied by read(=rscxd)
57271dfe => access_allowed: no more rules
```

It does not seem to read all my acls? does it ?

if so, it should be allowed to add an object with the "extra" user by alc #4 et #5 (with the write access), correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered - I believe - in the [OpenLDAP FAQ](http://www.openldap.org/faq/data/cache/634.html). Excerpts:

> Ordering is very important here. As soon as a subject match occurs,
>   the mask will be determined and resolution will stop.

The debug message is clear that at rule #3, there is a match. The `write by * read` component in rule 3 matches the requestor (`cn=extra,ou=system,dc=xxxxx,dc=xx`), so the processing stops. This means that you need to put the current rule 5 to come before rule 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bertold, it works like a charm. It is trivial when you find the right FAQ article!